# How to configure Squid to send back a HTTP 1.1 response for a HTTP 1.1 request?

Tags: http, squid

How to configure Squid to send back a HTTP 1.1 response for a HTTP 1.1 request?

I see that if a browser sends a HTTP 1.1 request, squid sends back a HTTP 1.0 response back even though the original web server that serves the content sends back a HTTP 1.1 response.

Answer (score 4):

That's because Squid doesn't fully implement HTTP 1.1.

Looking around for Squid's HTTP/1.1 status leads to http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTP11 and http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Http11Checklist ; the blog http://squidproxy.wordpress.com/ is also worth checking out. The [squid3 roadmap](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/RoadMap/Squid3) mentions further HTTP/1.1 support for 3.2

Answer (score 2):

Ticking the "Use HTTP 1.1" and "Use HTTP 1.1 through proxies" advanced settings under IE sometimes fixes related problems such as Bad Gateway and Zero Error replies from Squid